# Comparison Operator in Python

Tags: python, comparison-operators

I am learning python. I want to write a code where if my user is between the age of 18 and 22, they become eligible. If they are below 18, the underage message will display and similarly if they are more than 22 the overage message will display. This is the code I have written
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOLQa.png)

While running the code, if I put my age as 10 I get the correct response ie, 'sorry You are underage' but the same does not happen when I input 9 as my age. What am I missing here?

Comment: [how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow)

Comment: You’re comparing strings, but should compare numbers. Take a look at the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function to convert the input strings to numbers.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Woah, what version of Python supports that greater-equal operator?

Comment: @KellyBundy being the Kelly you are, the question is forgiven  That’s not a Python operator but a [ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)) of the [JetBrains Mono](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/#ligatures) font. I suspect the Op uses PyCharm.

Comment: @KellyBundy I am using PyCharm theme "Dracula material"

Comment: Kinda neat, although I'm not sure I'd want to get used to it. In any case, we can't execute images, so always post code as text, not image.

Comment: @KellyBundy Noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_age = int(input("please enter your age"))
```

input funtion return string so that we are converting into int.

you are checking string for logical operator. it won't work

try this.

```
if user_age > 0 and user_age < 18:
    print("under age")
elif user_age >= 18 and user_age <= 22:
    print("congrats")
else:
   print("over age")
```

Comment: Better version: `if 0 < user_age < 18:`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings.

```
if user_age > '8' # wrong
```

should be

```
if int(user_age) > 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did is a ASCII comparison, not numeric

9 != '9'